# Keyboard backlight

Tags: keyboard, samsung, backlight

I have a Samsung Series 7 NP700Z5AH with keyboard backlight.

After Ubuntu install it doesnt work, is it possible to fix?

There was a "Fucntion" shortcut for the sharpness of the light FN+F9/F10.

Answer (score 2):

I have a similar system; in 13.10 my keyboard backlight works after installing [Voria's PPA](https://launchpad.net/~voria/+archive/ppa).

To learn more about PPA please check [this question and answers](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4983/what-are-ppas-and-how-do-i-use-them) (especially useful is the [page on PPAs risks](https://askubuntu.com/questions/35629/are-ppas-safe-to-add-to-my-system-and-what-are-some-red-flags-to-watch-out-fo)).

In my Samsung (which is a 700Z5B) it works automatically but the auto on-off stops working if you try to change the lightness (under the "power" control settings).

**UPDATE 14.04.3** it now works automatically --- no PPA needed. It has still no control panel anywhere; it just works.

Comment: I get this when im trying to install:

'code' Failed to fetch http://no.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/g/guile-1.8/guile-1.8-libs_1.8.8+1-8ubuntu1_amd64.deb Cannot initiate the connection to no.archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:67c:29f4::51). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) [IP: 2001:67c:29f4::51 80]
Failed to fetch http://no.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/x/xbindkeys/xbindkeys_1.8.5-1_amd64.deb Cannot initiate the connection to no.archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:67c:29f4::51). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) [IP: 2001:67c:29f4::51 80] @Rmano

Comment: Which Ubuntu version and type have you installed? The repositories failing at you are not the PPA I pointed out...

Comment: I got it installed but no option for the keyboard light.

Comment: I simply installed it, rebooted, and the backlight is working alone when the light go down... really do not know what to do next. Sorry.

Comment: In your settings samsung-tools-preferences do you have a option for it?

Comment: which Ubuntu release - kernel do you have? Please add it to your question. Probably is a matter of newer kernel --- otherwise I do not know. (No, I have no `samsung-tools-preferences` anywhere.)